# How to route to subdomains in laravel

Tags: laravel, shared-hosting

My route not working on subdomain:

```
Route::domain('sub.example.com')->middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
   Route::get('/',function(){
    return 'Hi!';
   });
});
```

I'm using a shared linux cloud host.
When I visit sub.example.com it runs host default index.php in subdamin's folder!

Comment: You have to set fixed or wildcard subdomains allowance on your hosting provider. Something like adding new A record to your existing domain `A => *.existing-domain.com`

Comment: I added a A record but it didn't solve the issue! @Tpojka

Comment: If you added wild card subdomain it should resolve in browser i.e. you should be able to see website. Sometimes propagation of newly added sub/domain takes time.

Comment: It didn't work! @Tpojka

Comment: Add vhost configuration in question.